# How to XOR two images in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, xor

I want to XOR two images  in android  as iam working on image encryption app iam bringing images from SD card and loading them in image view now as i have loaded two images i want to XOR both of them

Comment: Go through pixel by pixel and XOR building a new image?

Comment: As DoomsKnight suggests, that may be your only option. Nested loops with XOR.

Comment: yup building a new image

Comment: Or just use `PorterDuff.Mode#XOR`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another alternative would be to draw on a `Canvas` both of your bitmaps. One bitmap does not specify any settings, but the other should specify a `PorterDuffXfermode` to `Mode.XOR`, in his `Paint` object.

Ex:

```
ImageView compositeImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

Bitmap bitmap1=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.batman_ad);
Bitmap bitmap2=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo);

Bitmap resultingImage=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap1.getWidth(), bitmap1.getHeight(), bitmap1.getConfig());

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultingImage);

// Drawing first image on Canvas
Paint paint = new Paint();
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, 0, 0, paint);

// Drawing second image on the Canvas, with Xfermode set to XOR
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.XOR));
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, 0, 0, paint);

compositeImageView.setImageBitmap(resultingImage);
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to xor, the pixels or data itself.
any way an easy way to do it is to convert the to images to array of all the pixels, XOR them together and then convert it back to a bitmap. NOTE that this example will only work to bitmap with identical resolutions.

```
//convert the first bitmap to array of ints
int[] buffer1 = new int[bmp1.getWidth()*bmp1.getHeight()];
bmp1.getPixels(buffer1,0,bmp1.getWidth(),0,0,bmp1.getWidth(),bmp1.getHeight() );

//convert the seconds bitmap to array of ints
int[] buffer2 = new int[bmp2.getWidth()*bmp2.getHeight()];
bmp2.getPixels(buffer2,0,bmp2.getWidth(),0,0,bmp2.getWidth(),bmp2.getHeight() );

//XOR all the elements
for( int i = 0 ; i < bmp1.getWidth()*bmp1.getHeight() ; i++ )
    buffer1[i] = buffer1[i] ^ buffer2[i];

//convert it back to a bitmap, you could also create a new bitmap in case you need them
//for some thing else
bmp1.setPixels(buffer1,0,bmp1.getWidth(),0,0,bmp2.getWidth(),bmp2.getHeight() );
```

see:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

Comment: + 1. Pretty much what I was thinking. You could make it work for different sized images, if you XOR the smaller one over the big one. So pixels that do not overlap, do not XOR and are left how they are.

Comment: it should be **setpixels** instead of getpixels and how to convert back to bitmap after seting it

Comment: There is no need to convert it back to a bitmap, it just override on of the bitmap with the new data

Comment: then how to diplay in image view ?

Comment: bmp1.getPixels(buffer,0,bmp1.getWidth(),0,0,bmp1.getWidth(),bmp1.getHeight() );
shoudnt it be buffer1?

Comment: yes you right that should be buffer1, and buffer2 rather than just buffer. you should display it the following way
ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimage);   

imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp1);

Comment: **out of memory ** exception is thrown

Comment: I haven't tested it on an android, but it should work.google "out of memory exception android". I guess you should define a bigger heap for your app.

Comment: its throwing exception in set pixels